# Do modules written in Typescript need a definition file for 'import'?

Tags: node.js, typescript

In NodeJS, do modules written in Typescript need a definition file?

I've written a module called 'deck-node' (available on NPM if you want to test) but when I `require` it within another Typescript module, with `require('deck-node');`, I get an error from the compiler that says:

```
/deck-node-app/app.ts(5,1): error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''deck-node''.
/deck-node-app/app.ts(5,1): error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

I thought Typescript does not need definition files for things already written in Typescript. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought Typescript does not need definition files for things already written in Typescript. Is this incorrect?

That is only true for things that are imported in a specific way. You can only require a typescript file relative to the current file. Arbitrary NPM import is not supported.

You can tell typescript about the external module using :

```
declare module 'deck-node' {
     //rest of the declaration
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks ! Is there an easy way to generate the definition file (the `definition` option of the Typescript compiler generates one for each file, which doesn't seem appropriate for this use case)? Or must it be written by hand and kept up to date with library changes?

Comment: @conradk unfortunately not at the moment. There are a few issues open regarding this. This one seems to pop up in my search right now https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2080

Comment: @basarat Is it still the case that modules authored in TS still require a .d.ts file on top of the source itself (which is typed?) and if so, is it still the case that there is no easy way to get from .ts to a representative .d.ts file?