# Error using prettyjson with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson with Typescript but it can't find the module.

I started with package.json:

```
{
  "name": "prettyjson-test",
  "description": "prettyjson with typescript",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.2.x",
    "npm": "3.3.x"
  }
}
```

Then I ran `npm install prettyjson --save`

Next I ran `tsd install prettyjson --save`

I created pj.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
import prettyjson = require('prettyjson');
```

Finally, I ran `tsc pj.ts --module "commonjs"`

C:\projects\pj\pj.ts(3,1): error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''prettyjson''.
C:\projects\pj\pj.ts(3,1): error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.

Based on [TypeScript won't resolve external module (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777131/typescript-wont-resolve-external-module-node-js), I'm guessing that the d.ts file is incorrect, but I'm not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an error in the .d.ts indeed. Looks like they forgot to put quotes ("") around the module name:

Changing `declare module prettyjson {` to `declare module "prettyjson" {` in the .d.ts solved it for me. Next step would probably be a pull request or a notification to the guys that wrote it.

Comment: The answer is always simpler than I first think.  Thanks!